# Juju bootstrap error tried all solutions with no success! Now what?

Tags: juju, maas

I need help with the juju bootstrap command.

I'm following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju) which references [this one juju specific](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS/Juju).

I followed the guide step by step but at the `juju bootstrap` command this is the error I receive:

```
2012-08-10 01:38:48,519 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: The supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server
2012-08-10 01:38:49,721 ERROR Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: The supplied storage credentials were not accepted by the server
```

I tried to change the MAAS API Key with no success.

I tried to modify the cobbler MEDIA_ROOT setting without success.

Is there a third option to overcome the issue? There are other questions with the same topic but no solution and I tried the given suggestions with no success.

Any other advice? Anyone from Canonical hanging around?

Here is the enviroments.yaml

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://10.10.10.201:80/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: 'GxeBxx3dYaPwVWKdGp:B2sQ2hukrmg5xMB2ej:nUwbL8eWDR2jVYfnFc9F3gDRHb4DQYSk'
    admin-secret: 'nothing'
    default-series: precise
```

UPDATE

Following the advice to remove the $ and curly braces I now receive the following error:

```
2012-10-12 13:49:00,967 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: Unexpected HTTP 500 trying to PUT http://10.10.10.201:80/MAAS/api/1.0/files/
2012-10-12 13:49:01,336 ERROR Bootstrap aborted because file storage is not writable: Unexpected HTTP 500 trying to PUT http://10.10.10.201:80/MAAS/api/1.0/files/
```

Comment: Question updated with requested data

Answer (score 2):

```
maas-oauth: '${GxeBxx3dYaPwVWKdGp:B2sQ2hukrmg5xMB2ej:nUwbL8eWDR2jVYfnFc9F3gDRHb4DQYSk}'
```

Try not including the shell quote bits, the guide intends you to replace all of ${maas-api-key} with the real value, not leave the dollar and curly braces in,

Comment: I removed the $ and curly braces but now I have a new error